# Using = operator in java with data structures

Tags: java, data-structures

My question is simple. If I have a data structure like a stack in java and add some elements, then I create other stack and equals to first stack using = operator (Example 1) instead empty the first one using while loop (Example 2). If i try to use the second stack in other scope, Can I lost the data if first stack is empty?

```
Stack<String> stack=new Stack<>();
Stack<String> stack_aux=new Stack<>();
stack.push("Hola");
stack.push("Mundo");
stack.push("in Java");
```

Example 1

```
stack_aux=stack;
```

Example 2

```
while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        stack_aux.push(stack.pop());
}
```

Comment: If you do `stack_aux=stack;` you are letting the variable `stack_aux` point to the existing stack, not creating a duplicate of the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we interview new Java programmers, this is one of the basic questions we ask.

```
What is the difference between =, ==, and equals() in Java?
```

Part of this is already answered in several other SO posts, [for example this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java). One of the Java basics not explicitly covered is that the = sign in Java is the *assignment operator*. That is, when you say

```
stack_aux=stack;
```

You are assigning the value of stack into the variable stack_aux.

When you do this, the value of stack_aux will be lost if you don't hold a copy of it in some other variable. This will happen regardless of whether stack is empty or not.

When you do this:

```
while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        stack_aux.push(stack.pop());
}
```

You will push the values of stack on top of stack_aux when stack is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a `stack` to another `stack`, you need to do something like:

```
stack_aux.addAll(stack);
```

You can't just use `=` in your Example 1

Your Example 2 will work just fine.

**Edit:**

Actually a better way is to use the `clone()` method:

```
stack_aux = (Stack<String>) stack.clone();
```

Comment: You should probably explain that `addAll` will only work in specific circumstances as it does not perform a deep copy. You should probably also explain what "deep copy" means or point to somewhere that provides a good explanation.

Comment: @D.B. yes - I guess my edit was supposed to say 'basically ignore the above and use the `clone()` method :)